# Como popular dados a partir de outra tabela quando um novo usuário for criado em AdonisJS

Tags: javascript, adonisjs

Estou iniciando em AdonisJS e me deparei com o seguinte cenário:

Possuo uma tabela de `user_config` que é populada a partir da criação de um novo usuário.

**Dúvida**: Gostaria de saber primeiro como faço para que após a criação do usuário, seja criada também um registro na tabela de `user_config` vinculado ao `User`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver da seguinte maneira:

Primeiro precisamos ter o relacionamento tendo a FK de user no registro de user_config.

```
class ConfigurationsSchema extends Schema {
  up() {
    this.create("configurations", table => {
      table.increments();

      table
        .integer("user_id") <------ AQUI
        .unsigned()
        .references("id")
        .inTable("users") <------ VINDO DAQUI
        .onUpdate("CASCADE")
        .onDelete("CASCADE")
        .notNullable();

      table
        .integer("expiration_document")
        .notNullable()
        .defaultTo(3);
      table
        .string("date_unit")
        .notNullable()
        .defaultTo("meses");
      table
        .date("warning_expiration")
        .defaultTo("01/01/2023")
        .notNullable();
      table
        .date("warning_expiration_sended")
        .defaultTo("01/01/2023")
        .notNullable();
      table.timestamps();
    });
  }

  down() {
    this.drop("configurations");
  }
}

module.exports = ConfigurationsSchema;
```

Depois precisamos informar o relacionamento entre as entidades nas models:

Dentro da classe UserModel:

```
  configuration() {
    return this.hasOne("App/Models/Configuration");
  }
```

Dentro da classe ConfigModel:

```
  user() {
    return this.belongsTo("App/Models/User");
  }
```

Depois precisamos definir no UserController o como funcionará o metodo store:

```
     async store({ request, response }) {
    //Buscamos os campos do corpo da nossa requisição e os armazenamos em um objeto chamado data;

    const data = request.all();

    //Criamos um novo usuário repassando os parâmetros vindos da requisição e salvamos esse novo usuário em uma variável user;
    const user = await User.create(data);

    await user.configuration().create({ user_id: user.id });

    //Retornamos o novo usuário como resultado da requisição, como selecionamos, no nosso caso o retorno será um JSON.
    return user;
  }
```